# ¿Cómo solucionar este problema con PDO SQLSTATE [HY093]?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Este es mi parte de mi código:

**crearpersonaje.php**

```php
<?php
$existenciausql=("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sv_cuentas WHERE Nombre = :n");
$stmt1=$db->prepare($existenciausql);
$stmt1->execute(array(":n" => $_POST['nombrePJ']));
  if($stmt1->fetchColumn()==0)
  {
  $registrosql=("INSERT INTO sv_cuentas (Nombre, Edad, Sexo, Skin, Cabello, Ojos, NickID, Nick, Registrado) VALUES (:n, :edad, :sexo, :skin, :cabello, :ojos, :nickid, :nick, :registrado)");
  $stmt2=$db->prepare($registrosql);
  $arrayDatos=array(":n" => $_POST['nombrePJ'], ":edad" => $_POST['edadPJ'], ":sexo" => $_POST['sexoPJ'], ":skin" => $_POST['skinPJ'], ":cabello" => $_POST['cabelloPJ'], ":ojos" => $_POST['ojosPJ'], ":nickid" => $nickid, ":nick" => $nick, ":registrado" => 2);
  
  if($stmt2 && $stmt2->execute($arrayDatos))
  {
  $saberid=("SELECT ID FROM sv_cuentas WHERE Nombre = :nombre");
  $stmtid=$db->prepare($saberid);
  $stmtid->execute(array(":n" => $_POST['nombrePJ']));
  
  while($row1=$stmtid->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
    $pjcid=$row1['ID'];
  }
  $setpj=("UPDATE sv_nicks SET Personaje0 = :pjcid WHERE ID = :nickid");
  $stmtpj=$db->prepare($setpj);
  $stmtpj->execute(array(":pjcid" => $pjcid, ":nickid" => $nickid));
  echo "<script>alert('Has creado tu personaje llamado ".$_POST["nombrePJ"]."');location.href='../';</script>";}
?>
```

Y me saltan estas advertencias:

> **Warning**: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in 'URL'.
>
> **Notice**: Undefined variable: pjcid in 'URL'

Sospecho que debe ser porque no da tiempo el SELECT a terminar el INSERT.

Comment: El problema parece estar al final del código, no sé bien qué intentas hacer aquí: `while($row1=$stmtid->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))` , lanzas un bucle casi sin sentido para asignar siempre en él un valor a la variable `$pjcid`, parece que no entra en ese bucle, porque uno de los mensajes dice que la variable `$pjcid` no existe. No veo coherencia en tu lógica, ¿ a qué se debe ese `while`? ¿Cómo controlas que la consulta no viene vacía?, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Si no me equivoco, la variable **$nickid** no tiene asignada ningún valor.
Diría que te falta hacer un $_POST['nickid'] o obtener el dato de alguna otra manera. Lo mismo con **$nick**.

Además, enla linea:

> $stmtid->execute(array("**:n**" => $_POST['nombrePJ']));

Debería ser:

> $stmtid->execute(array(":**nombre**" => $_POST['nombrePJ']));

Comment: Esas variables son obtenidas de columnas y sí están definidas. $nick=$row['Nick']; $nickid=$row['ID'];

Comment: No lo vi en el código. Edité mi comentario inicial, pues he añadido una cosa más :)